# Locating an element in a table if all elements have the same id

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to add some data and then check that it exists on page. The problem is that the UI when inspecting it with firebug looks very ugly. It was done using angular. I talked to the developer and he added some sensible ids for some elements. However, some of them, specially the table elements have the old namings. After adding the data, I want to do an assert that the element is present in table. This is my element:

```
<div id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code" class="d3-data-table-cell code" _    ngcontent-mrb-1="" ng-reflect-class-name="d3-data-table-cell code" ng-
reflect-id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code"> Test_Code </div>
```

The problem is that all the elements in the table have the id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code". Is there a way to get around this or is the solution renaming all elements on page?

I am doing the test using Selenium and Java.

Comment: You should try finding the elements by xpath.

Comment: It really depends on what you are looking for and how. Are you looking for a specific string to appear in a certain cell in the table? Or is it good enough that the string exists in the table anywhere or ? You should add some more details to your question and provide a specific example of what text you are adding and where you expect to find it. Please show the code you have tried and the result, error messages, and/or why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Id's are unique. Since id's can't be duplicated, you'll need to replace/renames these duplications.

In all cases, duplicate id's is forbidden.

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If your table is inside the  tag; you can try following code; which checks for every element inside table one by one, this way you don't have to worry about the elements having same id:

```
List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.cssSelctor("table tr"));

for(WebElement row : storeRows ){

 WebElement column = storeRows.findElement(By.agNamE("td"));

 for(int i=0; i<column.size();i++{

 if(column.get(i).getText().equals("value of your element"){

   //then do your action here

     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is trying to locate your elements by another identifier other Than the ID
Xpath for example  as it provides you a lot of useful functions to locate your Elements ex(parent element,child elements, ... etc)

Below URL is very useful if you will use Xpath methods

http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

if the different is in text and you know what the expected text you can use XPATH locator.

```
String xpath = "//*[text() = 'YOUR_TEXT']"
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.Xpath(xpath));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I am using for testing. So far it's passing but if anyone has any input please let me know:

```
public void testAddNewEntity() {
    String generatedEntityCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20).toUpperCase();
    String generatedEntityName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10).toUpperCase();

    EntitiesPage entitiesPage = new EntitiesPage(browser);

    entitiesPage.newEntity.click();
    entitiesPage.codeInputField.sendKeys(generatedEntityCode);
    entitiesPage.nameInputField.sendKeys(generatedEntityName);
    entitiesPage.parentCodeInputField.sendKeys("Next");
    entitiesPage.streetAddressInputField.sendKeys("Princess Street");
    entitiesPage.numberAddressInputField.sendKeys("31");
    entitiesPage.cityAddressInputField.sendKeys("London");
    entitiesPage.countryAddressInputField.sendKeys("UK");
    entitiesPage.zipInputField.sendKeys("312");

    entitiesPage.submitEntityButton.click();

    List<WebElement> codes = entitiesPage.entityTable.findElements(By.id("entity_data_manager_table_cell_code"));
    List<WebElement> names = entitiesPage.entityTable.findElements(By.id("entity_data_manager_table_cell_name"));

    Iterator<WebElement> rows = codes.iterator();
    Iterator<WebElement> nameRows = names.iterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        WebElement row = rows.next();
        if (row.getText() == generatedEntityCode) {
            Assert.assertEquals(nameRows.next().getText(), generatedEntityName);
        }

    }
}
```